# memcpy extremely unexpected behavior

Tags: c++

I'm using memcpy to copy information from and to an array that is getting written on disk. I'm storing **a char* of 256 bytes (name array)***, **3 long numbers**, and **a short number**. I thought it was going to work correctly until I tried it and it didn't. When saving the information to disk, everything seems to work just fine. But when trying to read off the information, memcpy simply malfunctions, leaving the variable directly after the name array at 0, and when my program needs it to load up something else, I end up with a seg fault.

At first I thought the information could've been getting corrupted when written to disk, or when being loaded from it, but I couldn't find any huge issues with the saving or loading procedures, so what I did next was to print out every single byte on the array (with Qt's qDebug), see if I could spot anything wrong with it.

Needless to say, it didn't work out as planned since qDebug only printed non null characters, and the "name array" has a lot of those, but it did something ridiculously surprising: it somehow made memcpy work and not work, since now it would successfully copy the first long number, but it would then corrupt the second long number. Thing is, the whole thing is pretty much unrelated!

```
            char* block = new char[FreeBlock::TablaMTD_v]; //3958 bytes long
            fRead.seekg(toLoad, ios::beg); //toLoad being an unsigned long file pointer, fRead being a working ifstream
            fRead.read(block, FreeBlock::TablaMTD_v); //reading all 3958 bytes to block
            fRead.close();
            short bsize = 0, pos = 0;
            memcpy(&bsize, block, 2);
            pos+=2;
            for(short i = 0; i < bsize; i++){
                char* tname = new char[257];
                unsigned long ptrmtd = 0, ptrdt = 0, ptrind = 0;
                unsigned short indmtd = 0;
                memcpy(tname, &block[pos], 256);
                tname[256] = 0;
                pos+=256;
                memcpy(&ptrmtd, &block[pos], 8); //without qdebug loop, stays at 0. otherwise, has correct value
                pos+=8;
                memcpy(&ptrdt, &block[pos], 8); //with qdebug loop, stays at 0. otherwise, has correct value
                pos+=8;
                memcpy(&ptrind, &block[pos], 8);
                pos+=8;
                memcpy(&indmtd, &block[pos], 2);
                pos+=2;
                for(int i = 0; i < FreeBlock::TablaMTD_v; i++){
                    qDebug()<<block[i]; //miracle solution, somehow
                }
                CampoMTDB* cmtd = nextCampoMTDB(ptrmtd, true); //based on ptrmtd, which if 0, returns null pointer
                unsigned long nextcmtdb = cmtd->next; //seg fault due to null pointer
```

Since that for loop is the only thing I have added, and commenting it/uncommenting it actually changes the outcome of the entire procedure, I'm quite honestly baffled. Sort of sets a new record for me on the "unexpected behavior" plane.

Taking into consideration I'm somewhat new to C++, and I've until recently heard of random dangerous practices I'm using here that apparently I should not be using, I still don't see how or why adding a random for loop AFTER memcpy operations would have any impact whatsoever on these operations, or why memcpy wouldn't work like it should in the first place.

Also note that after I saved my file, I didn't touch it again, it hasn't changed at all, yet the output from reading it changes.

In case it helps to know, I'm using VC2013 in Qt 5.3, x64 Windows 7

Comment: "I thought it was going to work correctly until I tried it and it didn't." -- welcome to the world of software engineering. ;-)

Comment: Are you sure that `sizeof(unsigned long) == 8` on your platform? In any case, for your own safety, you should probably use `sizeof` instead of those constant values of 8 and 2.

Comment: What the hack is a `char*` of 256 bytes? Maybe a `char*` pointing to 256 bytes?

Comment: And are you sure that sizeof(unsigned short)==2?

Comment: @Ilya `short` is really 2 bytes in the specified environment. But `long` is 4.

Comment: Question Error: No [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) found.

Comment: this is sad, I had not considered that at all. just tested, unsigned long is 4 bytes, unsigned long long is 8. That could in theory be it, I'd have to do some word replacing around my project, but I still don't really understand why the qDebug loop would have any impact whatsoever on the prodecure! D:

Comment: You should have written `memcpy(&ptrdt, &block[pos], sizeof(ptrdt))` - thus avoiding all those troubles. And if you want it to be portable and typesafe, use `Boost.Serialization`.

Comment: @BenjaminDover You shouldn't be hard-coding your data type sizes in the first place. Use `sizeof()`. Using platform independent types like `int64_t` from `<cstdint>` and endian translation functions would go the extra mile if you also wanted it portable, but it sounds like thats not really a concern for you right now.

Comment: Seriously, you should not write raw binary data to a file. You should write a proper serialization. There are tons of ready to use serialization formats and libraries out there: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_data_serialization_formats [Cap'n Proto](http://kentonv.github.io/capnproto/index.html) is very close to what you do (on-disk format == memory layout in process) with the added benefit of coming with formatting metadata and integrity checks.

Comment: @WhozCraig: indeed, I'm kind of in a hurry, but I do appreciate the advice since I'm working on really specific block sizes and most of them are based on things like 8-byte numbers, so using int64_t basically solves that issue!

Comment: @datenwolf: the project I'm working on is for a university class, and it's all based on handling files like this, so it's pretty much necessary for me to deal with these things myself.

Comment: @BenjaminDover: And you were taught in your class to write raw memory dumps without strict layout, datatypes, element sizes and byte/bit ordering? Time to change the class/teacher I'd say (seriously, after over 40 years of experience with fragile binary format files you'd think that they put the "how to properly design serialization formats" before teaching people how to write files).

Comment: @datenwolf: Teacher is useless, actually. He does zero code involvement and resorts to teaching with squares and lines. You're definitely not the first to say such a thing, and I agree with you. Sadly, I'm stuck with him for a while longer, so it's trial and error for me, at least for a bit longer. By no means do I plan on staying at this stage of poor coding knowledge, so I actually do appreciate the help everyone provided here.

Comment: @BenjaminDover: Regarding your current problem, binary data serialization, I suggest you read into the design documents of "Protocol Buffers", "Cap'n Proto", "BSON" and similar. They all follow roughly the same principles and a lot of experience went in the designs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using VC2013 under Windows 7, the size of `unsigned long` is 4 bytes (not 8 bytes).

And in any case, for your own safety, you should use `sizeof` instead of those constant values of 8 and 2.

Change this:

```
memcpy(&ptrmtd, &block[pos], 8);
pos+=8;
memcpy(&ptrdt, &block[pos], 8);
pos+=8;
memcpy(&ptrind, &block[pos], 8);
pos+=8;
memcpy(&indmtd, &block[pos], 2);
pos+=2;
```

To this:

```
memcpy(&ptrmtd, &block[pos], sizeof(ptrmtd));
pos+=sizeof(ptrmtd);
memcpy(&ptrdt, &block[pos], sizeof(ptrdt));
pos+=sizeof(ptrdt);
memcpy(&ptrind, &block[pos], sizeof(ptrind));
pos+=sizeof(ptrind);
memcpy(&indmtd, &block[pos], sizeof(indmtd));
pos+=sizeof(indmtd);
```

Comment: But this will also only work on exactly one platform. If you want to read a file which was written on an other system you run into trouble. I think that kind of handcrafted code should be avoided at all! Please use data types with known length! e.g cstdint. I would prefer a c++ solution and not a pointer/memcopy monster.

Comment: @Klaus: Thank you for pointing that out. I agree that this solution is good only if you're planning to write a file and then later read from that file, using the exact same platform.

Answer (score 0):

Since `sizeof(unsigned long) == 4` on your system, `memcpy(&ptrmtd, &block[pos], 8);` can modify memory that is not yours. It is very dangerous, so never do it.